# MS Word VBA Error: "The item with the specified name wasn't found"

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros, visual-basic, field-codes

I'm trying to set up a macro to adjust the field code of cross-referenced items so that only the numbers show, e.g. 3 instead of Figure 3.

I've found online that `\# "0"` can be added to the field code to do this and this does work. I need to do it quite often, though, so I tried to set up a macro by recording my keystrokes. This is the macro:

> Sub Macro1() ' ' Macro1 Macro ' '
>       Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
>       ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = Not ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes
>       ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Text Box 62")).Select
>       Selection.TypeText Text:="# ""0"""
>       ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = Not ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes
>       ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Text Box 62")).Select End Sub

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The field codes do show after I run it, but the macro just ends after that and I get the following error:

> **Microsoft Visual Basic**
>
> Run-time error '9':
>
> The item with the specified name wasn't found.

I have no idea how to fix this and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to simulate the situation you’ve described I inserted two Charts, then inserted Captions and finally inserted two Cross-references. As a result I got two fields with texts: *Figure 1* and *Figure 2*.

I used your findings on the `\# "0"` bit and put together the following macro which removes the text *‘Figure ‘* leaving only numbers. It only works for Ref field now but I guess can be used as well for other field types listed in WdFieldType enumeration.

```
Sub UpdateFieldCodes()
    For Each Field In ActiveDocument.Fields
        If Field.Type = wdFieldRef Then
            Field.Code.Text = Field.Code.Text & " \# ""0"""
            Field.Update
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```